# Maximum number of monitors Win 7 Supports

Tags: multiple-monitors

In a post sometime last year you wrote;

"... The maximum continuous windows desktop available is up to 32k horizontal pixels by up to 32k vertical pixels with an overall pixel limit of 128 million pixels..."

Is this based on some Microsoft/other reference doc or your practical experience perhaps? Looking for a definitive answer here - thx.

Comment: How many do you need exactly? I know it works with at least 6 because thats the number AMD cards can supports out of the box ( given the correct setup ). **Who said this exactly?** **Downvote issued until clarification is provided.**

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft support engineer Umesh P did not give a definite number in a similar question on Microsoft Answers. [He wrote](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-display-settings-applet-maximum-number/e7bc1cc2-9afa-4674-b5f7-513eb625a6d5):

> Hi Malcolm.Saffin,
>
> You are only limited by your ability to implement the hardware to support it. However, in order to make the maximum use of it and to make sure it works smoothly together, all of your video cards should use the same driver (It also depends on video card). If you use different video cards/drivers, it may not work properly.
>
> For more information visit the below links:
>
> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/work-and-play-better-with-multiple-monitors
>
> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Move-windows-between-multiple-monitors
>   http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx
>
> Thanks and Regards:
>
> Umesh P - Microsoft Support

BBlake says the same thing [in his answer](https://superuser.com/a/92732/20687)

> There is no "limit" per se set by Windows. You are only limited by your ability to implement the hardware to support it. However, in order to make the maximum use of it and to make sure it works smoothly together, all of your video cards should use the same driver. If you start mixing different video cards/drivers it starts to have problems.

Andrew contradicts this [in his answer](https://superuser.com/a/455981/20687) which I believe you quoted

> Windows does have a hard limit on maximum resolution and overall pixel count. The maximum continuous windows desktop available is up to 32k horizontal pixels by up to 32k vertical pixels with an overall pixel limit of 128 million pixels. Which means that a 32k x 32k desktop is not actually possible. Even video wall processors, which are generally purpose built windows dekstops, are constrained by these limits.
>
> Max pixels >= horizontal pixels(H) x vertical pixels(V)
>
> 128 Million >= H x V

This Microsoft blog post [boasts](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/25/pushing-the-12k-pc-gaming-boundary-at-1-5-billion-pixels-per-second.aspx) achieving 11,520 x 2,160 or about 24,883,200 pixels. Sorry, I looked for it but could not find a reference document from Microsoft contradicting the first quote.